# Can I make a CollapsingToolbar that collapses on a transition instead of on scroll?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I currently have a collapsing toolbar in one activity.  When pressing a button in a fragment in this activity, a new activity is opened that has a normal toolbar.  The same TextView is the title in both toolbars, and I would like the transition of the toolbar to look just like it does in the normal use of CollapsingToolbarLayout.  I have tried using a shared element transition between the two activities by using that TextView as the shared element, but it doesn't seem to be working.

So is it even possible to cause the "collapse" animation as a transition, or am I out of luck here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to collapse the toolbar like this:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
```

That animates it.
And then open your new Activity.

Comment: Thanks, pretty sure that would work.  But I am using Xamarin.Android and I cannot seem to find their version of setExpanded :/

Comment: You need to call it on your AppBar Layout. Not on the Collapsing Toolbar. The code in Xamarin is appBarLayout.SetExpanded(false, true);

Comment: Did it work? If so, kindly please mark as answer and upvote (-: . If not, I'll be glad to try to help.

Comment: Hi again, and sorry.  I tested in a separate project and that did work, so I will mark it as an answer :)  However, there are some things that cause it to not work in my project.  It collapses, but interferes with some other things.

Comment: Thanks. I'll be glad to try to help you with the project that it doesn't work with. You could post it as a different question and give me the link here in the comments.